# mysql_fetch_array gets the first result only, even with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to print multiple mysql rows, using **mysql_fetch_array** with **while loop** but it only prints the first result while my table contains many of them with the right conditions

```
$queryString="SELECT * FROM items WHERE order_id='".$order_id."' and confirm_order='0' ORDER BY id";
$myquery=mysql_query($queryString);

$handle = printer_open("POS");
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 35, 20, 300, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);

while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($myquery)) {

    $product=$fetch[product_name];
    $type=$fetch[type];
    $q=$fetch[item_quantity];
    $comment=$fetch[comment];

    $tex="".$q." ".$type." ".$comment." ".$product."";
    printer_draw_text($handle, $tex, 10, 10);
  }
printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
```

***Note:-*** and I can't use `mysqli` or `PDO` as I'm just testing something on an old project

Comment: [`$fetch[product_name]` should be `$fetch['product_name']`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) (this is a side remark, it doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: To find errors and warnings, put `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE); in front of the script`

Comment: `$product=$fetch[product_name];
    $type=$fetch[type];
    $q=$fetch[item_quantity];
    $comment=$fetch[comment];`
    
    Need to be:-
    
    `$product=$fetch['product_name'];
    $type=$fetch['type'];
    $q=$fetch['item_quantity'];
    $comment=$fetch['comment'];`(this is a side remark, it doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: @AlivetoDie — No, they don't. It's a best practise, but not a need.

Comment: I can't see any reason that the loop wouldn't work. Try looking at the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) or getting the code to output plain text in case it is an issue with your TeX library.

Comment: Consider using the mysqli extension instead of mysql.

Comment: thank all of you guys, I've tried all what you said but it still not working

Comment: @Quentin 2 Rows  mysql_num_rows got me 6 rows but still, only one prints

Comment: Also `$tex="".$q." ".$type." ".$comment." ".$product."";` can be `$tex="$q $type $comment $product";` (remove unnecessary quotes)

Comment: problem is `printer_draw_text($handle, $tex, 10, 10);` because it's write the new text at same x-y position which is 10,10.

Comment: please check your printer_draw_text(); function if it is return or its stop your loop so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [printer_draw_text Manual](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-draw-text.php)

> The function draws text at position x, y using the selected font.

In your code `x,y` values are 10,10. So each time new text written on the same postion. That means previous one over-written by new-one and hense only single value is drawn.

***There are two possible solution:-***

1.Either Change x,y position values after each iteration.

```
$counter = 10; //add a number counter

while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {//use assoc for lighter array iteration

    $product=$fetch['product_name']; //use quotes around indexes, best practise
    $type=$fetch['type'];
    $q=$fetch['item_quantity'];
    $comment=$fetch['comment'];

    $tex="$q $type $comment $product";//remove unncessary quotes
    printer_draw_text($handle, $tex, $counter, $counter); // use that number counter as x,y position
    $counter+10;//in each iteration chnage the value by adding 10
}
```

2.Or Create new pages in each iteration:-

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {//use assoc for lighter array iteration

    $product=$fetch['product_name'];//use quotes around indexes, best practise
    $type=$fetch['type'];
    $q=$fetch['item_quantity'];
    $comment=$fetch['comment'];

    $tex="$q $type $comment $product";//remove unncessary quotes
    printer_draw_text($handle, $tex, 10, 10);
    printer_end_page($handle); //end page on each iteration
  }
printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
```

Note:- Add rest of the code as it is.

Comment: @SophieBernard  glad to help you :):)